# functions that can take anything as argument

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a function that does something with whatever is passed to it, and returns a list based on that.

How would one go about processing and mashing whatever arguments are passed to it into one list that contains every value?

Also, the `'` is bugging me, as it makes calling somefunction2 from within somefunction1 problematic. Is there a way around this? It would be useful in my case to have an overly generic function that can take more or less anything as an argument, even other functions.

Possible arguments to the function:

- NIL (should be treated as 0)
- a number
- a list of numbers
- an empty list (should be treated as 0)
- several lists some of which may or may not contain NIL, numbers, or
- even more lists

Basically, what I want:

```
(somefunction '() 1 2 3 4 '(1 2 3 4 ) '(1))
```

...should be merged/mashed into:

```
(0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1)
```

... before being processed

*Note: this is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950323/defun-with-a-list-as-arguement)*

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a good place for learning the basics of a programming language. I propose to read some basic introduction text about Lisp or Common Lisp. There the basics of argument handling in Lisp will be explained in detail.

Comment: Seconding @Rainer. To get you started, check out [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) and [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html). If you're looking to get into AI specifically, maybe pick up a [Norvig](http://www.norvig.com/paip.html) or [two](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) (but those aren't free).

Comment: For whatever it is worth, NIL and an empty list are the same thing in Common Lisp, with () being used to highlight the listness and NIL to highlight the symbolness of this one thing that is bot ha list and a symbol (for, I understand, historical reasons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(defun weird-flatten (a)
    (cond ((null a) (list 0))
          ((atom a) (list a))
          (t (mapcan #'weird-flatten a))))

(defun foo (&rest args) (weird-flatten args))
```

EDIT: Noticed you're trying to do this as a learning exercise, so I guess I should explain. The first function is a pretty basic recursion. The only odd thing about it is that it uses `mapcan` rather than `mapcar`, so the result is merged into a flat list rather than retaining the same shape as the argument (um...`mapcar` takes an n-ary function and n lists as arguments and applies the function to each element of the lists, returning the resulting sequence; not sure whether that's too basic for you).

The `foo` function is a bit special in that it takes a `&rest` arg. This means that you can pass any number of things in to the function and the symbol `args` will be bound to the list of all arguments passed.

Why do you need `NIL`s to be treated as zeros, out of curiosity?

Comment: It's part of a larger project involving genetic algorithms. The genes are autogenerated lisp code, and mapping NIL to 0 is one way of making sure the genes stay somewhat on track with desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to map nils to 0, and then [flatten](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list) the result. You'll also need the &rest keyword(?) to snarf the arbitrary number of arguments into a single list.

(I'd consider producing some code, but I don't actually know CL.)